# Metric to assess interconnectivity between two communities/subgraphs

Tags: networking, graph, connectivity

Consider a large graph with several thousands nodes. Nodes belong to two communities (defined intrinsically by a node attribute). I am looking for a metric (if possible already implemented in gephi, cytoscape, or other software) able to tell me how much these two communities/subgraphs are interconnected (and compare several case studies). I am sure this must be a standard problem for people studying social dynamics in communities or network theory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use any of the objective functions optimized when performing community detection, see ([Fortunato 09](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0612)). The most widespread one is certainly the *modularity* ([Newman & Girvan 03](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0308217)), which is implemented in Gephi (see [this page](https://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Modularity)), and most other tools.

Edit: from your comments, you might be more interested in the [cut size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29) (number of links between the two communities), or one of its normalized variants such as the conductance, ratio cut, normalized cut. See [Fortunato'10](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0612) (section 4.1) for a review.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tested the modularity algorithms, but they don't really answer my need. They try to find communities based on node connectivity. What I want is the opposite: I already know the communities and want a metric expressing our much they are interconnected.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much the same thing. Modularity measures how much the communities are connected, for a given network and community structure (i.e. partition of the node set). Community detection methods based on modularity optimization just try to identify the best community structure by finding the partition of the node set leading to the highest modularity value. If you have already identified a community structure, it is relevant to process the modularity, which will tell you how modular your network is.

Comment: I am not sure if I was really clear. Let's say that we have the member lists of supporters of FC Barcelona and AC Milan, and we also know who knows who, which gives us a graph. Now what we want to understand is how much fans of FCB know fans of ACM, and vice-versa. That is more or less the type of data I have here. The "communities" are preidentified and therefore the output of a modularity detection algorithm would not be very informative (and especially would not give much quantitative information as far as I understand).

Comment: The modularity measure can be applied to any partition of the node set, indenpendently from the method used to obtain this partition: estimation via an algorithm (the usual), use of co-membership data (as you did), or others. However, it is meant to be compared to other values obtained for the same network (but different partitions), so maybe this is what is bothering you here. So, could you explain what you want to do with this measure, i.e. to what other value(s) will you compare it?

Comment: Thanks for your hanging on this topic. Actually, I am not aiming at comparing the values for different communities within the same network, but compare the connectivity of the same (types of) communities in different networks. For instance, in the previous example, perform the same method on supporters of Paris (PSG) and Marseille (OM), and then for example conclude on whether supporters of PSG and OM are more "familiar" with each other than the supporters of FCB and ACM.

Comment: Then you could just count the number of links between the communities. Or the proportion of links between them, if the considered networks have different sizes.

Comment: That is indeed what I have been thinking about. I was just wondering if other metrics had been published. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I edited my answer to address your comments. Note the modularity is actually the proportion of links *inside* the communities, with a correction for chance. This proportion is complementary to the proportion of links *between* communities, so the modularity and cut size are related.